# Bootstrap Carousel Indicators not working properly

Tags: html, css, web, bootstrap-4, carousel

I am designing a website for a client's portfolio. In the index I have a Bootstrap Carousel. This carousel shows the different projects, and I've created some indicators using text instead of the typical indicators. I will show you an image so you can see it.

[image: https://i.imgur.com/qfYssmL.jpg]

So here's my problem: the slides are changing properly, when I click the indicators it goes to the right slide, as expected. But the thing is that the indicators are not displayed as "Active", only the first one (which is active by default), because I wrote on the CSS that when an indicator is clicked (active, I guess), I want it to become orange.

In the image you can see the "Facebook" project in color orange, but actually the image that it's displayed and the indicator that I clicked correspond to the project called "Clasico".

I don't know what to do as everything looks to be well written and in its place.

HTML CODE

```css
.carousel {
  position: absolute;
  width: 895px;
  height: 638px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  top: 50%;
  -ms-transform: translateY(-30%);
  transform: translateY(-30%);
  margin-bottom: -30px;
}

.carousel-inner img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-heigth: 100%;
}

.carousel-caption {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.carousel-indicators {
  margin-bottom: -30px;
  text-align: left;
  float: left;
  color: #999999;
}

.carousel-indicators li,
.carousel-indicators li.other {
  width: 100px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 0;
  text-indent: 0;
  <!-- ww w.j a va 2s . c o m-->font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 19px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  margin: 0 2px;
}

.carousel-indicators span {
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.carousel-indicators li.active {
  color: #fcb970;
}

.carousel-indicators li:hover {
  color: #fcb970;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-10 col-lg-10 col-xl-10 text-center">
  <div id="slides" class="carousel slide carousel-fade">

    <ul class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#slides" data-slide-to="0" class="active other number-01"><span>Journey </span></li>
      <li data-target="#slides" data-slide-to="1" class="other number-02"><span>Suchard </span></li>
      <li data-target="#slides" data-slide-to="2" class="other number-03"><span>Ramps </span></li>
      <li data-target="#slides" data-slide-to="3" class="other number-04"><span>Facebook </span></li>
      <li data-target="#slides" data-slide-to="4" class="other number-05"><span>Products </span></li>
      <li data-target="#slides" data-slide-to="5" class="other number-06"><span>Lab </span></li>
      <li data-target="#slides" data-slide-to="6" class="other number-07"><span>Clásico </span></li>
      <li data-target="#slides" data-slide-to="7" class="other number-08"><span>Tribute </span></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <a href="https://gonzzzalo.com/work/journey"><img src="img/Journey.jpg"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <a href="https://gonzzzalo.com/work/suchard"><img src="img/Suchard.jpg"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <a href="https://gonzzzalo.com/work/ramps"><img src="img/Tutaller.jpg"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <a href="https://gonzzzalo.com/work/facebook-year-on-review"><img src="img/Facebook.jpg"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <a href="https://gonzzzalo.com/work/devices"><img src="img/Products.jpg"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <a href="https://gonzzzalo.com/work/varios"><img src="img/LAB.jpg"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <a href="https://gonzzzalo.com/work/clasico"><img src="img/Clasico.jpg"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <a href="https://gonzzzalo.com/work/tribute"><img src="img/Tribute.jpg"></a>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What browser are you using? Seems to work fine on my end in both Chrome and Firefox. I click through the links and they get coloured orange appropriately.

Comment: Everything's fine on my end as well, I got just one error that the page is trying to load scripts from unauthenticated sources, maybe you should check where your script files are loaded from and add them in secure way.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine on my end, although for the sake of your client's SEO you should add alt attributes to your images.

Comment: In both my computer and my laptop they are not working properly. I am using Chrome in both of them, but I've tried with Firefox and Safari, and still working wrongly.

The light orange of the hover is fine in all of them, but the thing is that only the first button ('Journey') works when clicked. The other buttons when clicked just get orange randomly, and even the last three are not working. I don't know what else can I try...

Comment: If one of the indicators works, but the other do not then it indicates that the other elements are outside of the scope of the CSS. You can either find what is causing the items to be outside of the scope, or just hack by giving each element it's own id and applying the CSS to each - not ideal, but it will work.

Comment: I've just solved it. The problem was that I had some other links with empty spans in between of the links I posted, so the thing was that these hidden links were over the right links, so I cannot press them. I removed the links with the empty spans and now its working.